# Taylorseries of ln(1 + x) with Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, taylor-series

I was trying to make a function, which computes the taylorseries of ln(1 + x), which takes a **z argument** (the value of **x**) and a **k argument** (till which term it should compute).

When I checked the function (with some **prints**) it goes wrong in the third term as it gives **2/3** instead of **1/3**. I've computed it on my calculator and it should go right, but I think I'm missing something. I hope I can be helped further!

[**Taylorseries of ln(1 + x)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LL2q.png)

**Code:**

```
# !{sys.executable} -m pip install sympy
import math
from sympy import *

from sympy import diff, sin, exp 
from sympy.abc import x,y 


def sum_deff_ln(z , k):
    expr = ln(1 + x)
    g = 0
    for aantal in range(g, k, 1):
        if aantal == 0:
            getal = diff(expr,x)
            q = g + 1 
            subantwoord = lambdify(x, getal)
            antwoord = subantwoord((g))*z**(q)
        elif aantal == 1:
            getal = diff(getal,x)
            print(getal)
            subantwoord = lambdify(x, getal)
            q += 1
            antwoord = antwoord + (subantwoord((g))/q)*z**(q)
            print(antwoord)
        else:
            getal = diff(getal,x)
            subantwoord = lambdify(x, getal)
            print(getal)
            q += 1
            antwoord = antwoord + (subantwoord((g))/q)*z**(q)
            print(antwoord)
        if aantal == k-1:
            print(antwoord)
            
sum_deff_ln(1, 3)
```

**Output:**

```
-1/(x + 1)**2
0.5
2/(x + 1)**3
3
1.1666666666666665
1.1666666666666665
```

Comment: A possible oversight with Taylor series is that in the nth term you divide not by `n`, but by `n!`. And `2/(3!)` is indeed `1/3`. I find it hard to follow your code with all that Dutch, but this is what I can think about given the `2/3` vs `1/3` problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be simplified as (without any packages):

```
def approx_ln(z,k):
    antwoord = 0
    for i in range(1 , k+1):
        subantwoord = ((-1)**(i+1) / i) * z**i
        antwoord += subantwoord
    return antwoord
```